# Unable to find a tab completion for Rubygem in Bash/Zsh

Tags: ruby, rubygems, tab-completion

I have not found a tab-completion script for RubyGem in Bash/Zsh.

**Where can you get the tab-completion script for RubyGem in Bahs/Zsh?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by tab-completion? Do you mean juts completing the commands available or completing the list of gems to install?

Comment: @Terence: I mean just completing commands available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executable RubyGem commands are installed into /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin or whatever prefix Ruby is found under.  Tab completion for commands should just work just like any other executable file in your PATH.  If it's not working, verify that the directory RubyGems installs commands into is in your PATH.

There is currently no official method of doing tab completion for the parameters to any of these commands.  If you need tab completion for a command installed via RubyGems, you'll need to write and/or install it yourself.  See the [Bash reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins) for details.  There may already be a completion system for the specific command you're interested in, so be sure to google for it, but most commands installed via RubyGems do not have any auto-complete written for them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
http://github.com/oggy/ruby-bash-completion
To install it just copy *gem* file to /etc/bash_completion.d/

I had errors when trying to tab:

```
gem install
```

Because I didn't have some cache files in .gem directory. So I simply disabled it by editing *gem* file. I changed _gem_all_names function:

```
function _gem_all_names {
   echo ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That github-hosted bash completion is now part of Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.  Sweet!  If you `apt-get install rubygems1.8` then the completion (commands and options!) should just work.

Unfortunately, as installed, it will only complete if it sees invocation of `gem1.8`, and not the more conventient `gem`.  You can fix that manually if so inclined by extending the last line of `/etc/bash_completion.d/gem1.8` to include `gem` as part of the `complete` name list.  I'm sure there's a cleaner way, but that works.

Answer (score 0):

This is (years) late, but as I was highly unsatisfied with the various completion scripts for `gem` that seem to be floating around the net, I decided to write my own based (somewhat) on the rather nice `git` completion script available in `git-sh`.

https://github.com/pdkl95/rubygems-completion